# Avahi not honoring its own /etc/avahi/hosts on the same machine

Tags: networking, avahi, host-name-resolution

## scenario

I want to use a mostly relatively light-weight way of associating IP addresses with hostnames.

For this, I've installed Avahi and mdns/nss on my Fedora distro.

I've like to use the pseudo-tld ".o" as a local domain, and not the default ".local".

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf` I've made sure that `mdns4` is set:

```
hosts:      files myhostname mdns4 [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

In `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` I changed one line and left everything unchaged:

```
domain-name=o
```

As my host name is `desk` this should make the domain `desk.o` available. That's my understanding, anyway.

Finally, in `/etc/avahi/hosts`, I've set one IP-hostname relation:

```
192.168.0.1 router.o
```

## expected behavior

Assuming my machine's name is `desk`, I'd expect the domain `desk.o` to be available.
Furthermore, I have machines in my network, which are unable to have their own Avahi running on them, so I'd use `/etc/avahi/hosts` to annouce those IP addresses, etc. One reason being, I have a pretty old network printer, which simply can't run Avahi, and I just have to use either the IP or something like Avahi (or just an entry in `/etc/hosts`).

So with the `hosts` file above, I'd expect `router.o` to be resolved to 192.168.0.1, etc.

## observed behavior

I've restarted Avahi after making any changes (`systemctl restart avahi-daemon.service`), but the way thing work is a little strange:

When running `getent hosts desk.local` I get this:

```
2a02:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:8878:583d desk.local
fe80::f990:519a:4ba5:9f22 desk.local
```

*(first IP partially obfuscated. Where there's an `x`, there were just hex digits)*

I'm fine with this (mostly), I wouldn't expect to `desk.local` be still available, but I'm assuming it's some sort of default that I can't get rid of (for now).

When running `getent hosts desk.o` I get:

```
127.0.0.1       desk.o
```

This is fine, as long as it's only on this machine, but it's a little odd to me, the FQDN hostname resolved to this.

When running `getent hosts router.o` I get nothing. Just no output.

## questions

So, apparently Avahi is ignoring `/etc/avahi/hosts`? I've restarted Avahi after making changes to that file, so I was assuming it'd be re-read.

Is Avahi not "publishing" the set hostnames to itself?

How to make Avahi and my system behave as I'd expect? Or am I having a fundamental thinking error here?

---

Ideally, an Avahi-hostname file would be somewhere in my `$HOME`, such that I don't have to adjust a system-wide hostname file for Avahi, if that makes sense. If that won't work, it's fine, since that'd go against the way hostname resolution works in principle, I suppose.

What kinda surprised me a little, is that `desk.o` is getting resolved (not as I'd expect it, really), but at least it resolves to *something* so it's at least partially working.

Comment: `desk.o` resolving to 127.0.0.1 is probably caused by the `myhostname` resolver module or by the synthetic entries of the `resolve` module +´systemd-resolved´, not by `mdns4`.

Comment: @telcoM right. So then Avahi doesn't work at all, really? At this point I'm asking myself whether there's a conceptional thinking error on my part...

Comment: It might be that `myhostname` just pre-empts it on local hostnames/IPs. Try `avahi-browse --all --resolve --terminate` and `avahi-browse --domain=o --all --resolve --terminate` to see what Avahi might be publishing/able to resolve.

Comment: @telcoM nothing, apparently, I'm getting `service_type_browser failed: DNS failure: NXDOMAIN` both times.

Comment: Avahi-daemon can apparently share the mDNS port (5353/UDP) with other software, but I’m not sure what happens if e.g. `systemd-resolved` gets it first. Please run `lsof -i udp:5353` and see if `avahi-daemon` actually has access to that port.